# How do I iterate over json result and add to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Good morning. 
I'm trying to add values from a json object to an array on page load.  I've tried iterating through it with for and in loops, but i can't reach the video names.

-ajax call-

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "/Search/GetVideoNamesForAutoComplete",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            //data: function () {
            //    var data = new FormData();
            //    data.append("videoName", $(this).val());

            //    return data;
            //}(),
            success: function (data) {
                var listofVideos = data;
                var objects;
                var sourceArray = [];

                var vidNames = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < listofVideos.length; i++) {
                    vidNames.push(listOfVideos[i].videoName);
                }

                console.log(listofVideos);
                jQuery('#autosearch').autocomplete({
                    source: sourceArray
                });
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log(errorMessage);
            }
        });
```

--Object--

```
listofVideos: Array(7)
0: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Kikoushi_Enma-01", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}
1: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Higurashi_no_Nakukoroni_01", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}
2: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Login Page - Internet Explorer 11_10_2018 9_06_09 PM", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}
3: {videoID: 0, videoName: "3killsmp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}
4: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Login Page - Google Chrome 10_28_2018 8_07_12 PM_Trim.mp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}
5: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Candle - 4101", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}
6: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Northernlights2_HD.mp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}
length: 7
```

Controller function

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetVideoNamesForAutoComplete()
        {
            DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
            NewVideosModel listOfVideoModels = new NewVideosModel();
            listOfVideoModels.listofVideos = new List<VideoModel>();
            DataTable dt = dl.GetVideoNamesForAutoComplete();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                VideoModel videoModel = new VideoModel();
                videoModel.VideoName = dt.Rows[i]["VideoName"].ToString();
                listOfVideoModels.listofVideos.Add(videoModel);
            }
            return Json(listOfVideoModels);
        }
```

--Console output for listOfVideoModels---

```
{listofVideos: Array(7)}listofVideos: Array(7)0: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Kikoushi_Enma-01", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}1: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Higurashi_no_Nakukoroni_01", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}2: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Login Page - Internet Explorer 11_10_2018 9_06_09 PM", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}3: {videoID: 0, videoName: "3killsmp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}4: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Login Page - Google Chrome 10_28_2018 8_07_12 PM_Trim.mp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}5: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Candle - 4101", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}6: {videoID: 0, videoName: "Northernlights2_HD.mp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null, …}length: 7__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object`
```

Comment: Update your browser or use the polyfill available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: My guess is you have an issue that we can not see if the incomplete sample code. Please show how you read the file with the ajax request.

Comment: @epascarello I updated the question with the ajax call

Comment: hm, not what I thought it was with that edit :)

Comment: Well you have an object and you treat it like you have an array.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use .map to map the value into an array. See below:

```js
var listOfVideos = [{videoID: 0, videoName: "Kikoushi_Enma-01", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "Higurashi_no_Nakukoroni_01", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "Login Page - Internet Explorer 11_10_2018 9_06_09 PM", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "3killsmp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "Login Page - Google Chrome 10_28_2018 8_07_12 PM_Trim.mp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "Candle - 4101", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "Northernlights2_HD.mp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}];


var videoNames = listOfVideos.map(v => v.videoName);
console.log(videoNames);
```

Or you can iterate it:

```js
var listOfVideos = [{videoID: 0, videoName: "Kikoushi_Enma-01", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "Higurashi_no_Nakukoroni_01", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "Login Page - Internet Explorer 11_10_2018 9_06_09 PM", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "3killsmp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "Login Page - Google Chrome 10_28_2018 8_07_12 PM_Trim.mp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "Candle - 4101", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}
,{videoID: 0, videoName: "Northernlights2_HD.mp4", createdbyUserID: 0, deletedByUserID: null, createdDateTime: null}];


var vidNames = [];
for(var i = 0; i < listOfVideos.length; i++){
    vidNames.push(listOfVideos[i].videoName);
}
console.log(vidNames);
```

Both options work just fine.

Comment: When i get to the for lop listOfVideos has an 'undefined' length.

Comment: Then you listOfVideos isn't an array. Are you sure you are using the right variable? If it is an array and isn't null it would have a length.

Comment: The only other thing i could think of is that it's a javascript object. let me add the controller function

Comment: Edit your question with the output from console.log(listOfVideos);

Comment: `var listofVideos = data;` should be `var listofVideos = data.listofVideos;`

Comment: Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop works above... but make sure there is a defined variable (empty array in this case) to hold the `videoName`s that you're pushing from iteration.

```
var videoNames = function(listofVideos) {
  var sourceArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < listofVideos.length; i++) {
    sourceArray.push(listofVideos[i].videoName);
  }
  return sourceArray;
}
```

Check out [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) from MDN that explains how this type of "mapping" works!